# How do i make discord bot buttons stay active after restart

Tags: typescript

So recently I have decided to make a discord bot. I have made a command with buttons and everything but I don't know how to make the button work after a restart. They just say interaction failed! I tried to make my own interactionCreate.ts but I never got it working. Thx in advance!

```
    import { Interaction, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageComponentInteraction } from "discord.js";
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";

export default {

    category: 'testing',
    description: 'Returns a Button',
    slash: true,
    testOnly: true,

    callback: async ({interaction:msgInt,channel}) =>{
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('Accept')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setLabel('ACCEPT')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
        )
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('Tenative')
            .setEmoji('‍♂️')
            .setLabel('TENATIVE')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        )



        await msgInt.reply({
            content: 'Are you sure?',
            components: [row],
            
        })




        const collector = channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
            max: 10,
        })

        collector.on('collect', (i: MessageComponentInteraction) => {
            console.log(`Button with id: ${i.customId} was pressed by ${i.user.username}`)
            i.reply({
                content: `Button with id: ${i.customId} was pressed by ${i.user.username}`,
                ephemeral: true
            })
        })

        collector.on('end', async (collection) => {
            collection.forEach((click) => {
                console.log(click.user.id, click.customId)
                
            })
        })


        
    },


} as ICommand
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the button a custom_id